# how do you add items at run-time to a listbox's items collection so like in design-time mode it can persist permanently

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, listbox, runtime

In a winform app when adding items to a listbox's items collection the items will persist and are available when the application starts but items added at run-time are not persisted the next time the app is launched.

How do you create the same design-time behaviour at run-time for saving the items permanently in the controls items collection without using any sort of databinding or serialization?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use serialization?

Comment: When you do it at design time the items get saved in the project file (.csproj). When you add them dynamically at runtime, they are stored in memory and you'd have to save them somewhere (database, file, etc.) and load them back next time you run the app.

Comment: you can persist to a Database, use Properties.Settings, you could save to xml file, txt file etc.. many ways to skin this cat

Comment: Design-time settings are actually in the Form's "Designer.cs" file, not the ".csproj" file.

Comment: My main goal is to avoid any interaction with the filesystem or any kind of database to mainly avoid any permission issues and to avoid the overhead and complexity of persisting the data to a database.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to commit the listbox items into your properties.settings so that when you application loads it will have the data. You will have to right click on the project you want to save the data for, then click on the "Settings" tab in the properties window. Within there you will be able to add each of the items. From there all you have to do is this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.myListboxItem = "Some new value";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

That segment of code will update the setting value you created, and it is very important you call the Save() because that is what commits the changes, so whenever you make a modification to any of the values in your settings call Save() at the end.

Then at the inital load, or on form creation you can do this:

```
myListBox.Items.Add(Properties.Settings.Default.myListboxItem);
// Repeat as needed
```

Comment: I was able to achieve what I was looking for with the Properties approach. Since I needed to work with a list I changed the type of Settings from string to a CollectionString and I was able to add or remove items to the list and have them persist. Thank You for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to create a text file that the program reads from at startup to load data into the listbox, and one that saves to the file when you add stuff to the listbox.

Loading is best done in the constructor:

```
class MyClass : Form
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        if (File.Exists("ListBoxItems.txt"))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("ListBoxItems.txt"))
            {
                while (sr.Peek() != -1)
                {
                    myListBox.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Other class functions here
}
```

Then, when you add items to your ListBox from within the application, let's assume you use a TextBox and a Button, and that Button adds the text in the TextBox to the ListBox, do something like the following:

```
public void AddToListBoxButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myListBox.Items.Add(myTextBox.Text);
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("ListBoxItems.txt",true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(myTextBox.txt);
    }
}
```

If the file doesn't exist when the form is loaded, there won't be any errors, and when you add to the list box it will create the file for you. All code is tested and works.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Great solution but the project properties worked out better for me.